# Why is my website subdomain title appearing in unknown language in Google when I search with its name in Google?

Tags: page-title

[When I searchee my website with "phd digitalindia, it shows the name in different language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uABHH.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQeWt.jpg)

When I search my website in google with "phd digitalindia", it shows my website name in unknow language. So, please help how can i fix this unknow name issue.